# sharepoint calculated column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I would ike to get just the email address from the column :Email From" in sharepoint 2007. Can  anyone please help me wrting the formula to get the  email id.

```
old value : abc, def <dabc@dxxx.com>
expected value: dabc@dxxx.com
```

How to write the expression so that i get something like that. Please help me.

I have added something like below in the calculated column, but somehow i cannot rip '>' symbol

```
=MID([E-Mail From],FIND("<",[E-Mail From])+1,FIND(">",[E-Mail From])-1)
```

and the o/p is

```
dabc@dxxx.com>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have it; maybe this tweak?

`MID([E-Mail From],((instr("<",[E-Mail From]))+1),((instr(">",[E-Mail From]))-1))`